# Jackson deserialize json that doesn't have keys (only values)

Tags: json, jackson

I have the following JSON response that I am trying to convert to a Java POJO:

```
[
    1393591550.6117706,
    "TYPE",
    "TAG",
    "Message",
    null
]
```

`(The null at the end is supposed to be there.)`

I am not sure how to deserialize this with Jackson (2.0). I am not too familiar with Json so I am not sure what to search. I have looked into keyless deserialization but there are lots of similar search terms and I can't find what I want.

The only idea I have is to use the getElements() of a JsonObject and manually map it to a log object (which is what this json is), but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this, like @JsonElement(0) or something. The way I have my project setup, having to manually iterate over keyless entries is going to require some major reworking (or duplicate code).

Comment: With keyless JSON entries you're usually stuck doing a static mapping by hand based on order of arguments in your own custom deserializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom deserializer, and then add this annotation to your class:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyCustomDeserializer.class)
```

In one of my projects, I do exactly that. A JSON Merge Patch is either an array or an object, so standard Jackson deserialization fails for me. The code for the deserializer is [here](https://github.com/fge/json-patch/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jsonpatch/mergepatch/JsonMergePatchDeserializer.java).

As to serialization, make your class implement `JsonSerializable`.

This has the advantage that you can {de,}serialize using a "vanilla" `ObjectMapper`, without having to configure it with custom modules etc

Comment: Thanks for this! I did not realize that you could annotate a specific deserializer in the class rather than using code to set it in the objectmapper.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually doable without custom deserializers, using something like this:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "value", "type", "tag", "mesage", "other" })
public class Data {
  public double value;
  public String type;
  public String tag;
  public String message;
  // not sure what the null is to represent; needs to match to this property
  public Object other;
}
```

and then you can read instances like so:

```
Data data = mapper.readValue(src, Data.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about writing a custom serializer / deserialize - with logic to handle NULLs? Check out this page from the docs:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers